# How to fix 'ANGLES was not declared in this scope' if it's declared

Tags: arduino

This is not my code but I don't get why it doesn't work. The define function is used to declare `NUM ANGLES` but it says that `ANGLES` is not declared.

I have tried to put the `#define` in all the scopes but this didn't work

```
#define NUM ANGLES 7
```

Does it help when I only declare `ANGLES` or something. This is the first time I'm using the arduino car kit 2wd and it's quite difficult.

```
/*
* Firmware for the ”2WD Ultrasonic Motor Robot Car Kit”
*
* Stephen A. Edwards
*
* Hardware configuration :
* A pair of DC motors driven by an L298N H bridge motor driver
* An HC−SR04 ultrasonic range sensor mounted atop a small hobby servo
*/
#include <Servo.h>

Servo servo;
// Ultrasonic Module pins
const int trigPin = 13; // 10 microsecond high pulse causes chirp , wait 50 us
const int echoPin = 12; // Width of high pulse indicates distance
// Servo motor that aims ultrasonic sensor .
const int servoPin = 11; // PWM output for hobby servo
// Motor control pins : L298N H bridge
const int enAPin = 6; // Left motor PWM speed control
const int in1Pin = 7; // Left motor Direction 1
const int in2Pin = 5; // Left motor Direction 2
const int in3Pin = 4; // Right motor Direction 1
const int in4Pin = 2; // Right motor Direction 2
const int enBPin = 3; // Right motor PWM speed control

enum Motor { LEFT, RIGHT };
// Set motor speed: 255 full ahead, −255 full reverse , 0 stop
void go( enum Motor m, int speed)
{
digitalWrite (m == LEFT ? in1Pin : in3Pin , speed > 0 ? HIGH : LOW );
digitalWrite (m == LEFT ? in2Pin : in4Pin , speed <= 0 ? HIGH : LOW );
analogWrite(m == LEFT ? enAPin : enBPin, speed < 0 ? -speed : speed );
}

// Initial motor test :
// left motor forward then back
// right motor forward then back
void testMotors ()
{
static int speed[8] = { 128, 255, 128, 0 , -128, -255, -128, 0 };
go(RIGHT, 0);
for (unsigned char i = 0 ; i < 8 ; i++)
go(LEFT, speed[i ]), delay (200);
for (unsigned char i = 0 ; i < 8 ; i++)
go(RIGHT, speed[i ]), delay (200);
}

// Read distance from the ultrasonic sensor , return distance in mm
//
// Speed of sound in dry air , 20C is 343 m/s
// pulseIn returns time in microseconds (10ˆ−6)
// 2d = p * 10ˆ−6 s * 343 m/s = p * 0.00343 m = p * 0.343 mm/us
unsigned int readDistance ()
{
digitalWrite ( trigPin , HIGH );
delayMicroseconds (10);
digitalWrite ( trigPin , LOW );
unsigned long period = pulseIn ( echoPin, HIGH );
return period * 343 / 2000;
}

#define NUM ANGLES 7
unsigned char sensorAngle[NUM ANGLES] = { 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120 };
unsigned int distance [NUM ANGLES];
// Scan the area ahead by sweeping the ultrasonic sensor left and right
// and recording the distance observed. This takes a reading , then
// sends the servo to the next angle. Call repeatedly once every 50 ms or so.


void readNextDistance ()
{

static unsigned char angleIndex = 0;
static signed char step = 1;
distance [angleIndex ] = readDistance ();
angleIndex += step ;
if (angleIndex == NUM ANGLES - 1) step = -1;
else if (angleIndex == 0) step = 1;
servo . write ( sensorAngle[angleIndex ] );
}


// Initial configuration
//
// Configure the input and output pins
// Center the servo
// Turn off the motors
// Test the motors
// Scan the surroundings once
//
void setup () {
pinMode(trigPin , OUTPUT);
pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
digitalWrite ( trigPin , LOW);
pinMode(enAPin, OUTPUT);
pinMode(in1Pin, OUTPUT);
pinMode(in2Pin, OUTPUT);
pinMode(in3Pin, OUTPUT);
pinMode(in4Pin, OUTPUT);
pinMode(enBPin, OUTPUT);
servo . attach ( servoPin );
servo . write (90);
go(LEFT, 0);
go(RIGHT, 0);
testMotors ();
// Scan the surroundings before starting
servo . write ( sensorAngle[0] );
delay (200);
for (unsigned char i = 0 ; i < NUM ANGLES ; i ++)
readNextDistance (), delay (200);
}

// Main loop:
//
// Get the next sensor reading
// If anything appears to be too close , back up
// Otherwise, go forward
//
void loop () {
readNextDistance ();
// See if something is too close at any angle
unsigned char tooClose = 0;
for (unsigned char i = 0 ; i < NUM ANGLES ; i++)
if ( distance [ i ] < 300)
tooClose = 1;
if (tooClose) {
// Something's nearby: back up left
go(LEFT, -180);
go(RIGHT, -80);
} 
 else {
// Nothing in our way: go forward
go(LEFT, 255);
go(RIGHT, 255);
}
// Check the next direction in 50 ms
delay (50);
}
```

Comment: and please indent your code.

Answer (score 1):

You could not use spaces in the first part of the define

```
#define NUM_ANGLES 7
```

Define is nothing more than a text replacement that replaces the first token with the rest of the line.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use spaces when delcaring a constant using a define. This is because a define is used by the [preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) and [not the compiler](https://www.calleerlandsson.com/the-four-stages-of-compiling-a-c-program/).
You have written:

```
#define NUM ANGLES 7
...
for (unsigned char i = 0 ; i < NUM ANGLES ; i ++)
```

The preprocessor converts this into a piece of text that the compiler will use to generate a executable program. The current preprocessor output of that piece is:

```
for (unsigned char i = 0 ; i < ANGLES 7 ANGLES ; i ++)
```

Because `NUM` is replaced with `ANGELS` and as such the compiler is looking for a variable named `ANGELS`.

If you write the `NUM ANGLES` without spaces: (and replace all other places where a space is incorrect)

```
#define NUM_ANGLES 7
```

Then preprocessor result will look like this:

```
for (unsigned char i = 0 ; i < 7 ; i ++)
```

That is indeed compilable code.

This all is because the format of a define is as follows:

`#define` *identifier* *token-string* *newline*

Comment: It would be 

   for (unsigned char i = 0 ; i < ANGLES 7 ANGLES ; i ++)